# How Do I Display a Name from a ListBox onto a TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display the name of the dog I selected into a textbox for a WPF app in C#. This is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace DogAdoption_Form
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    const string DISPLAY_NAME = "Name will display here...";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //DisplayLstBoxDogNames();    
    }

    public void DisplayLstBoxDogNames() 
    {
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Chloe");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Daisy");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Emmett");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Jack");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Lucy");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Nala");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Peach");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Rocky");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Shiloh");
        lstBoxDogNames.Items.Add("Toby");

        foreach (string dogName in lstBoxDogNames.Items) 
        {
            if (txtBoxName.Text == DISPLAY_NAME)
            {
                //txtBoxName.Text.Replace(DISPLAY_NAME, dogName);
                txtBoxName.Text = dogName;
                txtBoxName.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
            }

            else if ((txtBoxName.Text != DISPLAY_NAME) || (txtBoxName.Text == "")) 
            {
                //txtBoxName.Text.Replace(txtBoxName.Text, dogName);
                txtBoxName.Text = dogName;
                txtBoxName.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
   
    }

    private void txtBoxName_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayLstBoxDogNames();
    }

    private void txtBoxName_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBoxName.Text == DISPLAY_NAME)
        {
            txtBoxName.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
        }

        else if (txtBoxName.Text != DISPLAY_NAME)
        {
            txtBoxName.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that when I have the focus on the textbox, the font of the textbox will change from grey to black, and the content inside the textbox will switch from "Name will display here..." to the dog name selected from the Listbox. Currently, the window only displays Toby, the last element of the Listbox. The commented-out code was my attempt to replace DISPLAY_NAME with the selected item from the Listbox, but it didn't work. I've tried using lstBoxDogNames.SelectedItems.ToString();, but that didn't work, either.

Comment: The `if` statement in the `else` case is superfluous, because there `txtBoxName.Text` will always be unequal to `DISPLAY_NAME`. And if it is unequal to `DISPLAY_NAME` it can also be `""`. Use `lstBoxDogNames.SelectedItem.ToString()`, not `SelectedItems` (plural), because the latter is a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with `lstBoxDogNames.SelectedItem.ToString()` is actually not that bad. But if you debug, you will see that the string returned will not only contain the content that is being displayed, but also additional information.

Instead, try this:

```
string[] tmp = this.lstBoxDogNames.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
txtBoxName.Text = tmp[tmp.Length - 1];
```

`tmp` will get all of the elements seperated by a space in the selected item to string. Since the last of those elements is the actual content, it contains the selected name.

Feel free to ask a question if you didn't understand or if there is something to clarify.

Comment: When I do this, I get a NullReferenceException error with this information: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedItem.get returned null."

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. It was very simple. All I had to do was put the code that was inside `DisplayLstBoxDogNames()`  under the SelectionChanged event for the Listbox. Thanks for your help, everyone!